# code behind does not execute in dnn module

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, code-behind

I have installed DNN server, and created new DNN module in Visual Studio, using [Chris Hammond's project template](http://www.chrishammond.com/Blog/itemid/2616/using-the-new-module-development-templates-for-dot). I have added module to DNN as extension, and its client-side works fine. 
But I can not execute ASP.NET code behind part of project. I have tried to execute pre-generated Page_load() method, and also one button_click handler which I have constructed, but they just do not execute (I have tested with breakpoints, and also with code which should leave some trace in console, or in a file).
DNN documentation does not mention this issue. 
What am I missing here ?

Comment: Silly question, but does the DLL get put into the /bin folder in the root of the DNN website?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the WebForms pattern, on the .ascx file the top row will have `AutoEventWireup="false"` by default I believe.  Change that to True.  I've noticed a few people with this problem.

If this isn't the issue, make sure that you do not have a Cache time set in your .dnn manifest file.